# using a single global namespace, how to access properties/methods of the namespace from the methods of tools?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, closures, prototypal-inheritance

When building a variety of tools using a single global name-space, how do we access the properties or methods of the name-space object from the methods of tools, without going around on the outside so to speak?

Let `OT`, "Our Tools", be the name-space.

We could do:

```
var OT = function(){ // Closure
   var Turkey = 'Im a Turkey!';
   return this;
}();
```

**OR**

```
var OT = { // Object Literal
   Turkey:'Im a Turkey!'
};
```

In either case, we add our tools to the `OT` object such as:

```
OT.GridInterface = function (){
   // A Grid tool
   this.DoSomething();
}
OT.GridInterface.prototype = new OT.BaseInterface();


OT.GridInterface.prototype.DoSomething = function(){
   console.log(Turkey); // undefined
   console.log(OT.Turkey); // undefined with Closure, works with Obj Literal*
   console.log(this.Turkey); // undefined
}

// * This goes around the outside to get the property publicly rather than up through the inside.
```

It seems that each tool that is technically a method of `OT` and the methods of that method should be able to access the `Turkey` property of the namespace, since inner functions are supposed to be able to access properties of outer functions?

My goal is to be able to add shared config variables as well as some utility methods to `OT` that all tools that are methods of `OT` can use. Ideally, these tools and properties should be readable/usable from the tools, but immutable by them.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [here](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html), which explains more about private members in JavaScript.

Basically, what you are asking is not possible.

Either all of the functions have to be defined in the closure, or `Turkey` needs to be public.